# Keycloak CREATE TABLE APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES giving already exists error

Tags: java, mysql, kubernetes, keycloak, keycloak-services

Context:
I am installing **keycloak** using helm chart in a kubernetes environment. This creates a single deployment and pod with other required resources in my k8s environment. The image used in the helm chart is `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0`  . I am not doing any custom configuration and letting keycloak create the tables on start-up in the database (I am using MySQL). Previously I used the same keycloak chart with normal single instance oracle cloud MySQL database , where keycloak was able to create 92 tables required for its functioning.

Now when I switched to an HA(Highly available) oracle cloud MySQL instance , Then what is happening is , it is giving me this error :

```
2023-09-21 09:26:04,394 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to update database

2023-09-21 09:26:04,394 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for changeset META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.0.0.Final.xml::1.0.0.Final-KEYCLOAK-5461::sthorger@redhat.com:

     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES' already exists [Failed SQL: (1050) CREATE TABLE keycloak.APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES (APPLICATION_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ROLE_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL)]

2023-09-21 09:26:04,395 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Migration failed for changeset META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.0.0.Final.xml::1.0.0.Final-KEYCLOAK-5461::sthorger@redhat.com:

     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES' already exists [Failed SQL: (1050) CREATE TABLE keycloak.APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES (APPLICATION_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ROLE_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL)]

2023-09-21 09:26:04,395 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Table 'APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES' already exists [Failed SQL: (1050) CREATE TABLE keycloak.APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES (APPLICATION_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ROLE_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL)]

2023-09-21 09:26:04,395 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Table 'APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES' already exists

2023-09-21 09:26:04,395 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the
```

The issue is I had never seen this table in the single instance DB so why would this be created now? So I checked the keycloak repo for some clues. Here are my findings:

1. link to https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Akeycloak%2Fkeycloak%20path%3A%2F%5Emodel%5C%2Fjpa%5C%2Fsrc%5C%2Fmain%5C%2Fresources%5C%2FMETA-INF%5C%2F%2F%20APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES&type=code with search item as "APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES" :

here i found that using liquibase changesets, it is creating this table, making some relations and then renaming the table to **CLIENT_DEFAULT_ROLES**.

2. link to https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Akeycloak%2Fkeycloak+path%3A%2F%5Emodel%5C%2Fjpa%5C%2Fsrc%5C%2Fmain%5C%2Fresources%5C%2FMETA-INF%5C%2F%2F+CLIENT_DEFAULT_ROLES&type=code with search item as "CLIENT_DEFAULT_ROLES":

here I found that using liquibase changesets, it is modifying the CLIENT_DEFAULT_ROLES table and then dropping it in one of the changesets, so at the end it would not be visible.

My question is what made keycloak throw this error if in a single instance mysql it was working and in an HA it is giving this error?

**Note**: Previously it was giving me errors (only in HA env, in single instance it works flawlessly) related to the primary key as this table if you see in the change sets does not have a primary key so previous error was: **not able to create table** . But I switched off the primary key check(I know it is not recommended and will find another way but for now just to get to the root cause of the error i allowed it) so that this table can be created. Now after creating i do not know why every time on startup it is trying to create this table even after creating this once. Also due to this, only 30 out 92 tables are created and then it fails.

Please ask for any information required incase I missed something which can help in debugging.